# How to check if a string exists in a local web service using gatling?

Tags: scala, load-testing, gatling

I already have a simple request mapping **MVC service** running on the localhost.

It has **5 requests** each request displays a string "Greeting1 2 or 3 depending on which request it is. I would like to ***validate or implement a check method on my simulation script***. I have tried some snippets but they did not work

```
val scn = scenario("GreetingPages")
    .during(testTimeSecs) {
      exec(
        http ("greeting")
          .get("/greeting")
          .check(status.is(200))

      ).pause(minWaitMs,maxWaitMs)
      .exec(
        http("greeting1")
          .get("/greeting1")
          .check(status.is(200))

      ).pause(minWaitMs,maxWaitMs)
      .exec(
        http("Third page")
          .get("/greeting2")
          .check(status.is(200))

      ).pause(minWaitMs,maxWaitMs)

    }
```

Comment: what are you looking to validate? Is is a JSON response, or just some text in the body of a webpage?

Comment: {"message":"Greeting"} it comes out like this